# Angular JS: Disable ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Scenario : I am working with Angular js directive. I am working on making elements(i.e all anchor tags and buttons, apart from that, divs which consist ng-click as an attribute) disable. For that, I am using two directives. One for taking all elements which satisfies above mentioned condition and second directive for overriding that element's click event.

Problem : Till now, I got success in getting elements and applying directive dynamically on those elements. After that, I want to disable click event. 
My Question is, How can I make ng-click null and then once my conditions satisfies I have to execute same ng-click. 
Note: I am using $compile to compile html of the content. disableElement directive gets all elements and set ng-click attribute as null.But somehow,it is not working.

Goal: Making all element's ng-click disable.

```
// Disable Element Directive
app.directive('disableElement', ['$timeout','$compile',($timeout,$compile)=> {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    priority: 1,
    link: (scope, element, attr)=> {





        $timeout(()=> {
            if (condition satisfies get all elements and apply directive dynamically) {

                var allDivs = angular.element(element).find("*");
                var clickAction;
                for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
                    var currentElement = allDivs[i];


                    if (currentElement.attributes.length > 0) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < currentElement.attributes.length; j++) {
                            if (currentElement.nodeName == "a" || currentElement.attributes[j].name == "ng-click") {

                                //Gettting click action
                                clickAction = currentElement.getAttribute("ng-click");

                                //making ng-click null  
                                currentElement.setAttribute("ng-click",null);

                                //applying directive dynamically
                                currentElement.setAttribute("ng-demo","");
                                $compile(currentElement)(scope);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }





            }
    }, 1000);


    }
};
}]);

//ng-demo directive which overrides ng-click
app.directive('ngDemo',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: (scope, element, attr) => {

        var clickAction = attr.ngClick;
        element.bind('click', (e)=> {

            e.preventDefault();

        });


    }
};
});
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript...

Comment: The way you are trying to solve this, it won't work. You can't disable the ng-click directive itself once it's been compiled. Why don't you check for the condition in the callback function itself ? The implementation will be much more clean and concise.

Comment: Thank you for reply. @ExpertSystem
I am beginner in Angular. So can you please elaborate what are you trying to convey and give me any example which let me solve my issue.

Comment: I don't know how your app is set up in order to provide more concrete advice, but it would seem reasonable to do something like: `<some-element ng-click="someFunction()">` and inside `someFunction()`: `function someFunction() { if (condition.holds) { return; } else { /* do something */ } }` Then you only need to set `condition.holds` to `true` and `ngClick`s will be effectively disabled.

Comment: Ya,thats true. But in that case, I can only disable those elements which consists ng-click as their attribute but same way I want to disable anchor tags.(As I have checked in directive's conditions for both,elements having ng-click and anchor tags). So, what could be the way for disabling anchor tags and once condition does not satisfy it should be clicked

Comment: How do you plan to disabled anchor tags ? Change their `href` ?

Comment: Yes.I think, making their herf as a blank string or "#"  will work.

Comment: Then, you can handle them as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here is my solution in a jsfiddle.
Basically it invlolves capturing the ngClick events action during compile phase, storing that action elsewhere, nullify ngClick and then in the linking phase setting a click event with the stored action.

Changing the value of the custom directive between true and false will show results

http://jsfiddle.net/raleighvon/10wc2co6/5/

HMTL

```
<div ng-click="originalAction()" rv-deny-access="false" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  click me
</div>
```

JS

```
//Captures ngClick and lets it pass through if directive value is false
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('rvDenyAccess', function($parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  compile: function(elem, attrs) {
      var capturedOriginalAction = attrs.ngClick;
      attrs.ngClick = null;
      elem.removeAttr('ng-click');
      return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var value = scope.$eval(attrs.rvDenyAccess);
          if(value) { 
              // Can make a new action happen or prevent original action
              elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                  alert('Access denied!');
              });
          } else {
              elem.bind('click', function(e) {
                  $parse(capturedOriginalAction)(scope)
              });                
          }
      };
  }
};

});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.originalAction = function() {
    alert('Access granted!');
   };
}
```